# Retrieve multiple rows in Hbase using Get class based on non primary key values

Tags: java, hbase, bigdata

Using the methods in `Get` class in the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client` package, I am able to retrieve only one record at a time based on the row key.

Is there any way that multiple rows can be retrieved based on the value of any other non primary column(In java) .

Answer (score 1):

```
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getDataQualifierListByRowkeyList(String tableName,
        ArrayList<String> rowkeyList) throws IOException {

        Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));

        List<Get> getList = new ArrayList<Get>();
        for (String rowkey : rowkeyList) {
            Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(rowkey));
            getList.add(get);
        }
        Result[] results = table.get(getList);
        var funcResult = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (Result result : results) {
            var tempHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (Cell cell : result.rawCells()) {
                tempHashMap.put(
                    String.format("%s:%s", Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneFamily(cell)),
                        Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(cell))),
                    Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(cell)));
            }
            funcResult.add(tempHashMap);
        }
        return funcResult;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Get is only for one record which matches row key. For others, you can use scan with column value filters. This approach will have more latency time when compared to get. Get can also be used with list of gets(list of row keys). But you need get with field other than row key.

If possible, best approach would be, to design row key and add frequently searched field along with main row key. This is only if you need better latency.